# What are the Google Apps MIME Types in Google Docs and Google Drive?

Tags: mime-types, google-docs, file-type, google-drive-api

What are the MIME types for each of the following file extensions:

- gdoc
- gslide
- gsheet
- gdraw

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Google Docs:

`application/vnd.google-apps.document`
`application/vnd.google-apps.kix`

Google Presentations:

`application/vnd.google-apps.presentation`

Google Spreadsheets:

`application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`

Google Drawing:

`application/vnd.google-apps.drawing`

---

See [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/mime-types) for more information.

---

Here is a long list of Google Docs and Google Drive MIME types (it is not exhaustive):

```
application/vnd.google-apps.audio

application/vnd.google-apps.document

application/vnd.google-apps.drawing

application/vnd.google-apps.file

application/vnd.google-apps.folder

application/vnd.google-apps.form

application/vnd.google-apps.fusiontable

application/vnd.google-apps.kix

application/vnd.google-apps.photo

application/vnd.google-apps.presentation

application/vnd.google-apps.script

application/vnd.google-apps.sites

application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet

application/vnd.google-apps.unknown

application/vnd.google-apps.video
```

Comment: I found that I had to use application/vnd.google-apps.kix in order to view (only) Google Docs (.gdoc) in the Google Picker.

Comment: @Ali Afshar, Voteup for your useful answer. Thanks my compatriot !

Comment: I tried application/vnd.google-apps.kix & application/vnd.google-apps.document mime type but it gives me error "Invalid mime type provided".

Comment: application/vnd.google-apps.document its not working. my doc always in deselecting state

Comment: @Ali Afshar: Could you please tell me what's the difference between google drive file (application/vnd.google-apps.file) and other file types?

Answer (score 4):

This is my List of MimeTypes

```
     "application/vnd.google-apps.audio"
     "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
     "application/vnd.google-apps.drawing"
     "application/vnd.google-apps.file"
     "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
     "application/vnd.google-apps.form"
     "application/vnd.google-apps.fusiontable"
     "application/vnd.google-apps.photo"
     "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation"
     "application/vnd.google-apps.sites"
     "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
     "application/vnd.google-apps.unknown"
     "application/vnd.google-apps.video"
     "application/pdf"
     "application/msword"
     "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
     "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12"
     "application/vnd.ms-excel"
     "image/jpeg"
     "audio/mpeg"
     "video/mpeg"
     "application/zip"
     "text/plain"
     "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
     "application/vnd.android.package-archive"
     "application/vnd.google-apps.kix"
```

Comment: I have found this https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types but can I upload zip folder using  "application/zip" ? Please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

**(Jul 2016)** The answer by [@Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28380/ali-afshar) still stands today, addressing the OP's question of what are the specific MIMEtypes of Google Workspace (formerly G Suite, Google Apps) Drive "editor" (Docs, Sheets, Slides) files.

However, for the [Google Drive API](http://developers.google.com/drive), it's also important to clarify/organize the various supported MIME types that are used for importing files when uploading *to* Drive, i.e., [plain text or Word files to Google Docs](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2015/12/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html), as well as export MIME types when downloading *from* Drive, i.e., [Sheets files as CSV](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/07/exporting-google-sheet--as-csv.html).

- Drive [**import** MIMEtypes](http://developers.google.com/drive/web/mime-types)

  - [Chart of common import conversions & examples](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#import-docs)
- Drive [**export** MIMEtypes](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-export-formats)

  - [Downloads and exporting from Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads)

Answer (score -4):

For those of you trying to create a new editable Google Document, try with the following

```
DocumentApp.create("My new GDoc");
```

Comment: What programming language is this? What library are you using? I don't think this is useful

Comment: @Edd It's the Google Apps Scripts API. The reason of the post is to help someone looking for the specific MIME type of a Google Document file, which is different from a regular file.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I see where you're coming from now. I don't think this relates to the question though as it doesn't relate to mime types