# How to create an empty Google doc / Spreadsheet

Tags: google-drive-api

What is the best way to create an empty Google doc / spreadsheet?
I am using the GData docs / spreadsheet api right now but I'd prefer to use the Drive API.
Is there a mimetype that will create an empty Google Doc/Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/11415443/186674 for the list of Google Docs MIME types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating empty spreadsheets in Google Drive using Drive API (in Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741303/creating-empty-spreadsheets-in-google-drive-using-drive-api-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Claudio mentioned in the comment, you can see the list of the supported MIME types in the other question. In practice, its very easy to create a blank doc. For example:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files

{
'title' : 'My new document',
'mimeType':'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to add 'Content-Type: application/json' http header in the request. Otherwise I got '400 Bad Request - parse error'.