# Creating empty spreadsheets in Google Drive using Drive API

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I want to create an empty Google Sheet (created only with metadata) in Google Drive. When I referred to the Google [SpreadSheet API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#creating_a_spreadsheet) documentation, it says to use the DocumentsList API, but it's deprecated and instead asks me to use the Google Drive API. In the Drive API docs, I could not find any way to create an empty Sheet. Anyone have a clue on how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796827/how-to-create-an-empty-google-doc-spreadsheet and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412497/what-are-the-google-apps-mime-types-in-google-docs-and-google-drive should be helpful :D

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do this using the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) by setting the [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) to `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`:

To do this in Python:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
service = build('drive', 'v2')

import httplib2
credentials = ... # Obtain OAuth 2.0 credentials
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

body = {
  'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
  'title': 'Name of Spreadsheet',
}
file = service.files().insert(body=body).execute(http=http)
# or for version 3 it would be
# file = service.files().create(body=body).execute(http=http)
```

Head over to the [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.files.insert) to try it out!

Comment: How do I obtain OAuth 2.0 credentials??

Comment: "Head over to the Google APIs Explorer to try it out!"

Comment: I tried and it worked in the Google APIs Explorer. But I want to do it from python code and am having a hard time in the authorization part.

Comment: its not working,,i am able to create text file using "text/plain" MIME Type..but not spreadsheet

Comment: thanks for this, not because of the question. simply because it is the first example i found on how to post a model. All documentation i found uses get and list examples

Comment: Get this error:  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1427, in _generate_refresh_request_body
    body = urllib.parse.urlencode({
AttributeError: 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no attribute 'urlencode'

Comment: File an issue: https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/new It seems your install is broken.

Answer (score 14):

**(Jul 2016)** [BossyLobster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1068170/bossylobster)'s answer is still valid (as Drive API v2 has *not* been deprecated [yet]). However, below are more modern ways of doing the same thing and some videos to help with understanding:

**Authorization boilerplate for both examples below**

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
```

NOTE: to create your API project and OAuth2 credentials as well as download those credentials to the `client_secret.json` (or `client_id.json`) file, go to the [Google Developers Console](http://console.developers.google.com).

- To learn how to use the Developers Console, see [this video](http://youtu.be/DYAwYxVs2TI?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq&index=2).
- To walk through this boilerplate authorization code, see [this video](http://youtu.be/h-gBeC9Y9cE?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq&index=3). (NOTE: the boilerplate above is slightly newer/improved from the code in the video)
- To get an intro to using the Google Drive API v2 (listing your Drive files), see [this video](http://youtu.be/Z5G0luBohCg?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq&index=4).
- To learn about the Google Drive API *v3* (up/downloading files), see [this blogpost & video](http://developers.googleblog.com/2016/01/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html). (NOTE: v2 & v3 live side-by-side... v2 not deprecated yet; v3: fewer API calls, better performance vs. v2)
- To learn about the Google Sheets API v4 (migrating SQL data to a Sheet), see [this blogpost & video](http://developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/introducing-google-sheets-api-v4.html).

**Create new/blank Sheet w/[Google Drive API](http://developers.google.com/drive) v3 (& v2)**

```
# above: SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
data = {
    'name': 'My new Sheet',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
}
sheet = DRIVE.files().create(body=data).execute() # insert() for v2
```

**Create new/blank Sheet w/[Google Sheets API](http://developers.google.com/sheets) v4**

```
# above: SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
SHEETS = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
data = {'properties': {'title': 'My new Sheet'}}
sheet = SHEETS.spreadsheets().create(body=data).execute()
```

Now you may ask, "Why are there two different ways of creating a blank Sheet?" To put it succinctly, the Sheets API is meant primarily for spreadsheet-oriented operations, i.e., inserting data, reading spreadsheet rows, cell formatting, creating charts, adding pivot tables, etc., not *file-oriented requests* like create/delete and import/export, where the Drive API is the correct one to use. It just so happens that create is sort-of both, hence why there are two ways of doing it.

Comment: Can I specify in which folder of the google drive to create this spreadsheet on?

Comment: Yes you can. Check the documentation on how to do that: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create Look for the "parents" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The api reference to create spreadsheet is at https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create.

The code snippet to create a new spreadsheet is as follows.

```
String[] SCOPES = { SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS };

GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
        getApplicationContext(),
        Arrays.asList(SCOPES)).setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
credential.setSelectedAccountName("your_google_account@gmail.com");

HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets service =
    new com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets.Builder(
        transport,
        jsonFactory,
        credential)
    .setApplicationName("Google Sheets API Android Quickstart")
    .build();

Spreadsheet spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
SpreadsheetProperties properties = new SpreadsheetProperties();
properties.setTitle("SpreadSheetTitle");
spreadsheet.setProperties(properties);

service.spreadsheets().create(spreadsheet).execute()
```

Comment: The good news: this uses the newest version of the Sheets API, v4. The bad news: the OP was requesting a Python example.

Answer (score 1):

you could also try the [pygsheets](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets) library i wrote , It ofcourse provies more features than just creating spreadsheets,

```
import pygsheets

gc = pygsheets.authorize(outh_file='client_secret.json')

# Open spreadsheet and then worksheet
gc.create('my new sheet')
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed methods did not work for me, but the following code works:

```
# requires: uid='example@gmail.com', pass1='password', 
# name_spr='name_of_spreadsheet'

import gdata.docs.client

docs_client = gdata.docs.client.DocsClient()
docs_client.ClientLogin(uid, pass1, 'any')
document = gdata.docs.data.Resource(type='spreadsheet', title=name_spr)
resource = docs_client.CreateResource(document)
full_id = resource.resource_id.text # returned by gdata
gs_id = full_id[len('spreadsheet:'):]
```