# How to create a Spread Sheet on Google Drive Using Java and Drive API

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet on google drive using DRIVE API in Java, the documentation on google site is very confusing, can somebody please help me by pointing to a sample example that demonstrate the creation of documents on google drive in Java using the latest DRIVE API?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217995/how-to-programmatically-create-a-google-docs-spreadsheet-with-content), using Drive API seems to only let you create new empty files with the spreadsheet MIME type. The Drive API is only concerned with operations at the whole file level. It is only possible in Google Drive to upload the created spreadsheet.

You can use [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) (formerly called the Google Spreadsheets API) which lets you develop client applications that create, read and modify worksheets and data in Google Sheets. This API can manage the worksheets in a Google Sheets file. You should strongly consider using a GData client library to interact with the API. Follow the following steps [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#setting_up_your_client_library) to setup a development environment for working with the Sheets API.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a spreadsheet via Drive API by calling [files.create()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create) with `mimeType=application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet` and uploading a CSV file. See [Importing to Google Docs Types](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_wzxhzdk8wzxhzdk9) where there's a Java sample.