# Google Drive mime-types listing?

Tags: google-drive-api

As per https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads, it mentions

*See the API reference for each method's list of accepted mime types and size limits for uploaded files.*

I was unable to find mime type listing at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/
Where can I find it?

Comment: It's true you can store any file type on Google Drive per Ali below. However, MIMEtypes themselves are used more specifically when desiring import or export conversion with Drive. See my SO answer to *that* question, including links to both lists of MIMEtypes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38406284/305689

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry it isn't listed in the documentation. It is easy, though, you can store any MIME type in Google Drive with files up to 5TB in size.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats?hl=en

Answer (score 102):

```
$mime_types= array(
    "xls" =>'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    "xlsx" =>'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    "xml" =>'text/xml',
    "ods"=>'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet',
    "csv"=>'text/plain',
    "tmpl"=>'text/plain',
    "pdf"=> 'application/pdf',
    "php"=>'application/x-httpd-php',
    "jpg"=>'image/jpeg',
    "png"=>'image/png',
    "gif"=>'image/gif',
    "bmp"=>'image/bmp',
    "txt"=>'text/plain',
    "doc"=>'application/msword',
    "js"=>'text/js',
    "swf"=>'application/x-shockwave-flash',
    "mp3"=>'audio/mpeg',
    "zip"=>'application/zip',
    "rar"=>'application/rar',
    "tar"=>'application/tar',
    "arj"=>'application/arj',
    "cab"=>'application/cab',
    "html"=>'text/html',
    "htm"=>'text/html',
    "default"=>'application/octet-stream',
    "folder"=>'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
);
```

In addition, here is a list of mime-types specifically pertaining to Google drive (and the google suite): https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code only answers are almost as bad as link only answers. They're not really answers at all. A good answer contains explanations and reasoning and possibly some sources or authority.

Comment: @markus , this answer does not satisfy your defenition but is perfectly clear and helful..

Comment: You aren't seriously trying to include all existing MIME types here, are you? There is no such list, any vendor/user can invent their own ones (I personally used "application/xml" to prevent Request Tracker from displaying XML attachments).

Comment: i am usong db so i searched but didnt find mime type for database for drive while using this  .setMimeType(new String[]{"application/x-sqlite3"}) but it didnt work pls help

Comment: csv files downloaded from google sheets end up as 'text/csv' for what it's worth

Answer (score 15):

I found a **complete list** of file extensions and mime types from **Google** itself in GitHub:

[**google-drive-proxy / DriveProxy / API / MimeType.cs**](https://github.com/google/google-drive-proxy/blob/master/DriveProxy/API/MimeType.cs)

---

From Drive REST API [reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert):

> **Maximum file size:** 5120GB
>
> **Accepted Media MIME types:** `*/*`

In other words, you can use **any mime type** that matches the pattern `*/*`.

Here is the [**IANA list of official media types**](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). You can learn more about media types [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type).

Comment: best answer right here

Comment: agree, really the best answer

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open Here you can find the official listing of gdrive mimetypes.

Answer (score 0):

It's specified in the doc page for each method, as it says.

For example:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Shows: "Maximum file size: 10GB, Accepted Media MIME types: */*" near the top of the page.

If you're uploading (inserting) files, you can set the mime-type of the file yourself.  The size/mime limits only apply to (as far as I can tell) the insert and update methods.