# What are the file types in the file metadata ("exportLinks") in Google drive API?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am developing a wrapper which called google drive api and retrieve exportLinks for the Google document in drive. I am trying to write a function to automatically identify the available links and assign to readable html href. So far, some of the type of files are :

1. application/pdf
2. application/rtf
3. application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
4. application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
5. text/html
6. text/plain

I don't know how much there are and I want to know where I can find all type of files that Google Drive Api allow us to download.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) all possible mime types are allowed.

```
Accepted Media MIME types: */*
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894772/google-drive-mime-types-listing