# Google Drive - Is it possible to create programatically an xml file?

Tags: android, xml, google-drive-api, google-docs

This question may sound a bit ridiculous to those who read it. But I am in a crucial situation where I need to find an answer to these questions.

Scenario :- We are supposed to create an app with two modes. Client mode and User mode.Client Mode - Hotel's can register and add their cuisines(including every single sub category). User mode - users can open app and view different Hotels which are registered. On selecting each Hotel users can view the different cuisines under different categories.

Concerns :-

1. Is it possible to create and upload xml file to Google Drive programmatically ?
2. How we can add endless data in an xml ? I mean  each Hotel's cuisines will be different from another Hotel. Also the categories and sub categories and sub in sub categories will also be different. We (developers) are not supposed to limit the categories or the sub categories to any limit. The user should be able to input every single cuisine available and edit, delete them accordingly ?

   **EDIT**

   - While Googling I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894772/google-drive-mime-types-listing) post which list out the file formats supported to create files in Google Drive. It doesn't mention xml in it.

Has anyone done something like this or something similar to this before ?

Suggestions & Opinions are welcome.

Comment: An xml file isn't any different from any other file in Drive. What have you tried?  What isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Drive API](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi.html) to interface with Google Drive to manage user data for your application.

XML files are exactly the same as any other text file, with the caveat that you should add the MIME type "text/xml" to the Metadata for your Drive files.

As for "endless" data, XML allows an unlimited numbers of nodes underneath any parent, you might want to go with a structure that defines cuisine categories under one node, then a collection of products in a separate node with a category mapped to it.

For example,

```
<HotelCuisine>
 <categories>
  <category id="1" name="Category 1" />
  ... List any additional categories here
 </categories>
 <products>
  <product>
   <name>Product 1</name>
   <category>1</category>
  </product>
  ... List any additional products here
 </products>
</HotelCuisine>
```