# Convert uploaded file to Google Documents format

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload files to Google Drive but with the attribute `convert=true` to allow a automatic conversion of upload file to Google Docs format...but it does not work:

```
$drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle("Informe-imaxbd-alfa");
$result = $drive_service->files->insert($file, array(
'data' => file_get_contents("notas-gdrive.docx"),
'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
'uploadType' => 'multipart',
'convert' => FALSE,
));
```

The file is properly uploaded but without any conversion, why?

Comment: sorry I've tried too with 'convert'=>TRUE,

Comment: The problem is related with 'mimeType' putting the right mimetype (in this case application/msword, and the conversion is now working fine.

Comment: Complete list of mimetypes in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894772/google-drive-mime-types-listing

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, that the proper mime type Google Drive API accepts is `application/msword`. I also found out as of writing this, Google Drive API does not support Word .docx format conversion for some reason.

So make sure that not only your extension is in .doc format, but actual document content is also older .doc (Word 97 - 2004) format.