# Unable to preview/open doc uploaded into Google doc via Google API?

Tags: google-docs-api

I've recently integrated Google Drive's API into a website that I'm building on CodeIgniter. The website is all about writing an essay and converting that into Word document that I've managed to upload into Google Drive using the API script provided

However, I'm not able to preview or open the uploaded document right on Google Drive. But, I'm able to view and edit it once I download the Document from Google drive and open via Microsoft Word processor
please advise what I should be doing to make my document editable on Google drive using Google doc's tool.

here is the coding that I used to upload the document generated from the website and here is the sample document attached.

Please Note: Like I aforementioned, when I re-upload the document that I download from Google drive back to Google drive then the document works fine and I'm able to preview as well as edit it.

```js
     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $client->getAccessToken()) {
     // We'll setup an empty 1MB file to upload.
     $doc_file = $this->session->userdata('google_doc_file');

   DEFINE("TESTFILE", __DIR__ . '/../../../papers/'.$doc_file.'.docx');

   // This is uploading a file directly, with no metadata associated.
     $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
     $file->setName($doc_file.'.docx');
     $result = $service->files->create(
      $file,
      array(
        'data' => file_get_contents(TESTFILE),
        'mimeType' => 'text/docx',
        'uploadType' => 'multipart'
         )
       );
      }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630793/convert-uploaded-file-to-google-documents-format

Comment: Google Drive is not showing images on Documents uploaded by the Google Drive API? please help

Comment: do you have an example doc?