# Android Google Drive API how to set non-MIME file format

Tags: android, google-drive-api, mime-types, google-drive-android-api

I have some file on my device, which I want to upload (and later download) to Google Drive. When creating a file on Drive, I have to set it's MIME type:

```
MetadataChangeSet.setMimeType("text/xml");
```

So, we have some specific MIME types, which allows us to upload different files.

But what I have to do if my file formats are not in this MIME-list? 
How can I upload/download files with formats like .style, .map, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I've found a solution.

You can specify your own MIME type like this (for example `.style`):

```
String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType("style");
```

It worked for me, at least.

Answer (score 3):

**But what I have to do if my file formats are not in this MIME-list? How can I upload/download files with formats like .style, .map, etc.?**

I think file formats that are not in MIME list will not be accepted since the file type is invalid. Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894772/google-drive-mime-types-listing), any vendor/user can invent their own MIME types and you can store any MIME type in Google Drive with files up to 5TB in size.

Comment: `any vendor/user can invent their own MIME types`   but I thought, that I have to create a new MIME type on a server side. Is it possible to upload my own MIME type file to Google Drive?

Comment: Or what's more important - if I will download file with incorrect MIME type from Drive, will my app on device read it correctly? For example - if I download a file with `plain/text` with .jpeg type, will it open like .jpeg or .txt?