# How to download google drive file in android

Tags: android, file, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I wanted to download file from google drive. 
For this I have implemented in Google Drive SDk and used the following method.

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_OPENER:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                DriveId driveId = (DriveId) data.getParcelableExtra(
                        OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);


            }
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

I also tried using output stream but not able to save data to a file.

I have tried searching around this, but couldn't find any useful link which can guide me how to download and store file.

Comment: Have you seen https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files ?

Answer (score 8):

IMO, you should read some useful links below:

- [Google Drive APIs Android - Guides - Working with File Contents](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files)
- [Google Drive Android API Demos at GitHub](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos)

Then, please refer to the following snippets, of course when getting the input stream, you can save it to a file in your device instead of printing to Logcat.

```
public class GoogleDriveActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {           
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgressBar.setMax(100);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)  
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RC_OPENER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mSelectedFileDriveId = data.getParcelableExtra(
                    OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult result) {
        // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
        // Do something...
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {        
        // If there is a selected file, open its contents.
        if (mSelectedFileDriveId != null) {
            open();
            return;
        }

        // Let the user pick a file...
        IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                .setMimeType(new String[]{"video/mp4", "image/jpeg", "text/plain"})
                .build(mGoogleApiClient);
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, RC_OPENER, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    private void open() {        
        mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        DriveFile.DownloadProgressListener listener = new DriveFile.DownloadProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(long bytesDownloaded, long bytesExpected) {
                // Update progress dialog with the latest progress.
                int progress = (int) (bytesDownloaded * 100 / bytesExpected);
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("Loading progress: %d percent", progress));
                mProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        };
        DriveFile driveFile = mSelectedFileDriveId.asDriveFile();
        driveFile.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, listener)
                .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
        mSelectedFileDriveId = null;
    }

    private final ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback =
            new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error while opening the file contents");
                        return;
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "File contents opened");
                    
                    // Read from the input stream an print to LOGCAT
                    DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(driveContents.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    try {
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            builder.append(line);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String contentsAsString = builder.toString();
                    Log.i(TAG, contentsAsString);

                    // Close file contents
                    driveContents.discard(mGoogleApiClient);
                }
            };
}
```

Comment: Error while opening the file contents

Comment: Post the screenshot or logcat contain that error message, my code has been tested with a .txt file and a .jpg file in my Google Drive

Comment: 06-26 11:20:39.815  24640-24640/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@266f8698 time:412814845
06-26 11:20:45.585  24640-24640/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@266f8698 time:412820613
06-26 11:20:48.475  24640-24640/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo D/retrieve_contents﹕ Loading progress: 0 percent
06-26 11:20:49.495  24640-24640/com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo W/retrieve_contents﹕ Error while opening the file contents

Comment: Which file did you open? Moreover, can you post the screenshot of your app when open that file?

Comment: And please try with other files (for example some text files, some .jpg files, make sure the files are not corrupted)

Comment: getting started.pdf

Comment: For PDF files, have you used `application/pdf` with `setMimeType` method yet?

Comment: My logcat with a PDF file `D/GoogleDrive: Loading progress: 0 percent
...
D/GoogleDrive: Loading progress: 100 percent
I/GoogleDrive: File contents opened
I/GoogleDrive: %PDF-1.5%����1 0 obj<<    /Type /Catalog   ...>>startxref2242%%EOF`, I think you can check with some other files

Comment: I am trying it but can't click on any file disable click on drive why??

Comment: @SunilChaudhary I think you should read https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-sdk and https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth

Comment: i did this can't Select means mimetype is not supported I am trying to backup db file to drive but when it save to drive its file type change from file to Unknown and then when getting it Using driveIntent can Select

Comment: @SunilChaudhary try using `zip` or `rar` file instead, perhaps some useful links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894772/google-drive-mime-types-listing https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types

Comment: @BNK I received contentsAsString. i given all MIME type. I tried to write this content in device memory. I written successfully. But i am not able to open file.  I tried with PDF, image

Comment: @selva_pollachi I have not tried writing files, however, please check your code as Google's guided at https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files, from "Writing files" section

Comment: I am reading xls file from drive and writing it into "download.xls" file created by me. Contents gets written successfully but when i open the file, it says file contents corrupted.