# Activating Triggers in Google Spreadsheet Scripts with Google Drive SDK

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Phrased another way, is there a way to:

1. Create a new Google Spreadsheet (from the Google Drive API)
2. And then create a Google Apps Script associated with that Google Spreadsheet programmatically
3. **And then programmatically activate the "On Edit" and "On Form Submit Triggers" to call various methods in the script? (this is the part I cannot figure out)**

-OR- (as @JacobFlatter suggested)

1. Manually create a spreadsheet with the desired script
2. Use the Google Drive API to programmatically copy the spreadsheet (which copies with script with it as well)
3. **Somehow programmatically activate the "On Edit" and "On Form Submit Triggers" (which DO NOT copy over from copying the spreadsheet, this is the part I cannot figure out)**

Answer (score 1):

Possible path to follow:

Create a container bound script with an onOpen() trigger within a spreadsheet.

Copy the existing Spreadsheet (which will copy the script as well) programmatically.

Open the new Spreadsheet programmatically (unsure if this will initiate the trigger described above).

This assumes a few things, but seems like it is worth investigating.  I'm curious if this works.  Good Luck.

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for the suggestion! So I tried copying an existing spreadsheet and the script does indeed copy programmatically. However, the triggers do not ("On Edit" & "On Form Submit"). Any ideas how to activate these programmatically somehow on the new spreadsheet?

Comment: Nice, I think at this point you should be able to use the ScriptApp api.  Check out [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder](Build Triggers With ScriptApp Api) .  I hope that helps.

Comment: OHH! Are you saying that inside of the onOpen() trigger (that already exists in the script) to then run the triggerBuilder stuff? Is that what you mean? That's genius, will go try it!

Comment: Or you can build a new onOpen trigger after you copy the file.  I am glad you have a few avenues to try.

Comment: How do you build an onOpen trigger with the REST API? I don't think I understand how to make a REST command to the Google Scripts API, can't only the Google Drive API do that? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I am a little confused what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you originally creating a new Spreadsheet from REST or from Google Apps Script?

Comment: Either way, you can use Apps Script to create a trigger, after copying the file.  Start by creating a google apps script (separate from spreadsheet script.google.com) and either call the function from Google Apps Script, or use the doGet() function and publish the script as an HTTP endpoint.

Comment: I can outline this later if this is starting to make sense.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, no. You cannot do meta programming with Apps Script. 
Based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412497/what-are-the-google-apps-mime-types-in-google-docs-and-google-drive), I wrote a simple function to try meta programming

```
function meta(){
  var mime  = 'application/vnd.google-apps.script'; 
  DocsList.createFile('MetaScript','function test(){}', mime);

}
```

It throws up an error saying `Invalid mime type`

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I phrased my initial question clearly... I mean using the REST API, can I create a Google Spreadsheet, and then use the REST API to add a Google Apps Script to that Spreadsheet?

I'm not quite sure how meta programming is relevant to this but maybe I'm missing something?