# Google Drive App - context menu item for Spreadsheet

Tags: google-drive-api

I have made a Google Drive app and I now have trouble getting my app to be shown for the "Open with" menu.

In the Google Apps Developer console I have registered "text/csv" as the primary mimetype and checked "Allow users to open files that can be converted to a format that this app can open.".

I have tried, as a test, to add the mimetype "text/plain". Then I can access Google Docs files fine in my app.

My questions is, what mime type should I register to be shown in the context menu for Google Spreadsheet files?

Comment: Hi Do you get your answer ? I have the same issue when I had the mime type application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheetI get an error in the developper concole saying the user request is not valid after clicking on save modifications.

Answer (score 0):

The MIME type for a Google Spreadsheet would be "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet". Also for the extension of Spreadsheet is ".gsheet".

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412497/what-are-the-google-apps-mime-types-in-google-docs-and-google-drive) and [here](http://fileinfo.com/help/google_drive_file_types) for more info on different MIME types for Google files and their extensions.

Hope that helps!