# Create google sheets on team drives through API's

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Below code creates a google sheet on My Drive but what if I had to place this to a folder on team drive?

I would like to modify createNewSpreadSheet function in such a way that it uploads file to specified folder of team drive.

```
        function createNewSpreadSheet(auth) {
              const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
          const resource = {
          properties: {
            title:'SampleSheet'
          },
        };
        sheets.spreadsheets.create({
          resource,
          fields: 'spreadsheetId',
        }, (err, spreadsheet) =>{
          if (err) {
            // Handle error.
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log('spreadsheet::',spreadsheet.data.spreadsheetId);
          }
        });
        }


        // Load client secrets from a local file.
        fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
          if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
          // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Sheets API.
          authorize(JSON.parse(content), createNewSpreadSheet);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You may check this [blog](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2017/06/managing-team-drives-with-python-and.html) on how to **import/upload files to Team Drives folders**.

> Uploading files to a Team Drives folder is also identical to to uploading to a normal Drive folder, and also done with `DRIVE.files().create()`. Importing is slightly different than uploading because you're uploading a file **and** converting it to a G Suite/Google Apps document format, i.e., uploading CSV as a Google Sheet, or plain text or Microsoft Word® file as Google Docs. In the sample app, we tackle the former:
>
> ```
> def import_csv_to_td_folder(folder_id, fn, mimeType):
>         body = {'name': fn, 'mimeType': mimeType, 'parents': [folder_id]}
>         return DRIVE.files().create(body=body, media_body=fn+'.csv',
>                 supportsTeamDrives=True, fields='id').execute().get('id')
> ```
>
> The secret to importing is the MIMEtype. That tells Drive whether you want conversion to a G Suite/Google Apps format (or not). The same is true for exporting. The import and export MIMEtypes supported by the Google Drive API can be found in my SO answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38406284/305689).